# Comparing Feature Responses from Two Deep-Learning Frameworks

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, correlation, feature-extraction

I am extracting two feature responses from two separate machine/deep-learning frameworks.  I now have two matrices that have NxF dimensions where N is the number of samples and F is the number of features.  I want to do a comparison of how similar the learned features are.  I have tried several things, but the main idea is using correlation (tried Pearson and Spearman) to correlate the feature responses into a FxF matrix.  I then take the absolute value, max across a single axis, and then compute the mean of those max values.  I actually have several frameworks that I would like to compare, but I am getting very similar results.  Has anybody done this?  Does anyone else have any better suggestions? My code sample is below.

```
from scipy.stats import spearmanr
import numpy as np

def similarity(resp1, resp2):
    rho, p = spearmanr(resp1,resp2)
    corr = rho[:resp1.shape[1],resp1.shape[1]:]
    sim_mtrx = np.abs(corr)
    feature_match = np.max(sim_mtrx,axis=1)
    return np.mean(feature_match)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Has anybody done this? Does anyone else have any better suggestions? My code sample is below.

To be honest this makes no sense. Why? Because there is no ordering in features in things like deep nets. Consequently comparison you are doing cannot be used to draw any reasonable conclusions. Your matrix `N x F` is probably your weight matrix from your first layer. Consequently each of (column) vectors of these matrices represent **a single neuron**. The trick is - `i`th neuron in one network (trained with one framework) can has nothing to do with `i`th neuron in the other one, while it might be identical to `j`th. For example consider a network trained on images with `F=3`, you might find that these neurons learned to detect horizontal (neuron 1), vertical (neuron 2) lines and maybe a circle (neuron 3). Now you train again, either with different framework, or even with the same one but different random seed. Now even if this second network learns exactly the same thing - to detect horizontal line, vertical one and a circle - but simply in different neurons (like horizontal-2, vertical-3, circle-1) your method will claim that these are completely different models, which is obviously false. The problem of "having similar representations" is a research direction on its own.

The minimum you have to do is to find **best matching** between neurons in two networks, before applying basic analysis you are proposing. You can do this by brute forcing (F^2 possible mappings, just take the one claiming the biggest similarity) or use something like Hungarian algorithm to find perfect matching.

The most imporatnt thing is to keep **reference comparison**, to avoid problems like the above, so instead of training a single model per framework, train **at least 2** per framework. And now instead of claiming "method A and B produce (dis)similar representations because representations generated by a single experiment with A and B are (dis)similar" you should check whether there is a statisticaly significant difference between (dis)similarity between two runs (with different seeds) of the same algorithm  and single runs of two different algorithms, in other words:

- you have 2 algorithms A, B (frameworks)
- you create representations A1, A2, B1, B2
- you test whether mean(sim(A1, A2), sim(B1, B2)) != mean(sim(A1, B1), sim(A2, B2)) (while previously you were just checking if sim(A1, B1) is "big")

### Update

Just to show why the metric considered is wrong, lets use it on:

```
>>> x
array([[0, 3, 6],
       [1, 4, 7],
       [2, 5, 8]])
>>> y
array([[ 6,  0,     0],
       [ 7, -1,  -123],
       [ 8,  0,  1000]])
>>> similarity(x,y)
1.0
```

You end up with just **a single** match, you do not care that 90% of data is completely different - you still report maximum similarity.

Comment: I did simplify the problem for Stack Overflow, but I do indeed have two frameworks A and B.  I trained these frameworks with two different sets of data to give us a A1, A2, B1, and B2.  I assumed that I could find a similarity metric that gave us what you describe above.  I would assume that A1 ~ A2 and B1 ~ B2.  Does the similarity metric I provided above make sense for this?  Neuroscience papers seem to use 1 - linear (Pearson) correlation for dissimilarity in the past.

Comment: As I said in the first part of the answer - no, it does not. This metric is not permutation invariant, and you need this property. Code, on the other hand does not implement correlation check, it performs maximum correlation check, feature-wise. Consequently it ignores 90% of the data when assigning a value.

Comment: That example was helpful in showing why my metric is not correct.  I got confused with the "best matching" reference since I thought that was what I was doing with the max function.  I am not so much concerned with the location as I am with I can find feature responses that are similar to one another.  I was trying to reproduce something similar to Figure 9 in https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2605405/pdf/fnsys-02-004.pdf.  They are trying to find dissimilarity between model responses.  It seems to me that they are using simple correlation to build the RDMs.

Comment: Again - what is proposed here does not work, not for neural nets. Find the best matching (which means you find for each neuron in one net, which one is the most similar in the second one, and compute correlation in this pair). This way you will get some notion of similarity (however it can still yield false negatives, since there are many very similar in "human" sense - filters/models which do not have high correlations. For example if these are images, you can just translate everything by one pixel and correlation will be random, yet filters nearly the same.